# PKCE in spring oauth2 client for is not sending correct payload when doing POST request to /token endpoint of idp

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client

i'm implementing a spring oauth2 login mechanism that act as a client to an external identity provider, my code was working well when using oauth2 without pkce.
the requirements has changed and now i have to implement the challenge_code in the authorization request and the code_verifier in the token request.
looking on spring documentation for add pkce was mandatory override the DefaultServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver, so i added this bean

```
    @Bean
public ServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver pkceResolver(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository repo) {
    var resolver = new DefaultServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(repo);
    resolver.setAuthorizationRequestCustomizer(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestCustomizers.withPkce());
    return resolver;
}
```

another thing to do  was add in the securityfilterchain configuration method the new resolver

```
    @Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http, ServerLogoutSuccessHandler handler, ServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver resolver, ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository repository) {

    http.oauth2Login(auth -> auth.authorizationRequestResolver(resolver));
    http.oauth2Login().authenticationFailureHandler(failureHandler());
    http.cors().disable().csrf().disable()
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/actuator/**", "/login/**","/logout.html")
            .permitAll()
        .and()
            .authorizeExchange()
            .anyExchange()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
              .jwt();           
    http.logout().logoutSuccessHandler(handler);

    return http.build();
}
```

now the challenge_code is in the request done to external idp.
the idp redirects again in the application with the authorization_code and the state.
Now the app should send a POST request to the idp provider /token endpoint but it fails with this error message

```
    Suppressed: org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: [invalid_client] FBTOAU229E Confidential clients accessing the token endpoint must authenticate using their registered credentials.
```

the logs say that there is a bad request

```
HTTP POST https://exampl.it/mga/sps/oauth/oauth20/token, headers={masked}
Writing form fields [grant_type, client_id, code, redirect_uri, code_verifier] (content masked)
Response 400 BAD_REQUEST, headers={masked}
Decoded [{error_description=FBTOAU229E Confidential clients accessing the token endpoint must authenticate using their registered credentials., error=invalid_client}]
```

how can i see that values? I tried with a request interceptor but is not catching nothing.
I can't find a way to solve the problem and i don't really understand which is.
PLEASE HELPP I'M 1 WEEK STUCK IN THIS PROBLEM :(

Answer (score 0):

According to the message, you have a client authentication issue. Check `client-id`, `client-secret` and `client-authentication-method` in your application properties.

##### side note

According to [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/client/authorization-grants.html#_initiating_the_authorization_request), you can do simpler:

```java
DefaultServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver.setAuthorizationRequestCustomizer(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestCustomizers.withPkce())
```